# Shopify subscription but doesn't start until second billing cycle

Tags: shopify, subscription

I would like to set up a Shopify subscription model that starts with 1 main product but allow for recurring subscription of "refills" for the product. However the "refills" would should only start on the second month as the main product includes the first set.

Is there a subscription app that allows for this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

That is completely supported by the Shopify Subscription API. If you try the various Apps that support Subscriptions, and they do not provide for this functionality, make a support request. You'd be surprised how easy it can be to get them to add basic stuff. Otherwise, roll your own App and you can make a plan that has this functionality without too much fuss.